# How does uniform continuity and continuity affect the convergence of a function

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Say we are working in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

In the below cases what can we say about the convergence?

1) $f_{n},f$ are continuous and $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}=f$

2) $f_{n},f$ are uniformly continuous and $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}=f$

---

Furthermore how would the above cases effect the use of the D.C.T on

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}$$

Comment: 'Are' $f$ continuous\uniformly continuous or  the functions in the sequence $f_n$?

Comment: both, I have edited .

Comment: Do you mean the convergence is $L^\infty$ convergence or pointwise? (just to be sure).

Comment: Both? Im not sure im confused

Comment: Well $L^\infty$ convergence implies uniform convergence which is stronger than pointwise convergence.  Pointwise convegence does not imply convergence of the integrals, but uniform convergence implies convergence of the integrals on a compact set.

Comment: I should add that $L^\infty$ functions are not necessarily integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, for example $f=1_{x\leq 0}(x)-1_{x>0}(x)$.